# Can you please help me write this out in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, vector

[image]

I need help writing this diagram in tikz and my skills are not yet advanced enough to do it. Can any of you help me? Please?

so far all I have done is this

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \draw (2,2) circle (.5cm);
 \draw (2,2) circle (3cm);
 \draw[-stealth] (-4,4)  arc (80.0026:40:1) ;
\draw [-latex,very thick] (2,2)  -- node [above,near end,rotate=90] {${T}$}(0,-4);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I don't know what to do after or how to do the correct arrow.

EDIT

I got it a bit further but I still need help

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \draw (2,2) circle (.5cm);
 \draw (2,2) circle (3cm);
 \draw[-stealth] (-4,4)  arc (80.0026:40:1) ;
\draw [very thick, ->] (2,2)  -- (2,-1.5) node [above,near end,rotate=90] {${T}$}(2,-1.5);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Saying that your skills are not *advanced enough to do it* yet, means that you actually have some skills however limited they might be. So please make the effort to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I managed to do this so far 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \draw (2,2) circle (.5cm);
 \draw (2,2) circle (3cm);
 \draw[stealth] (,-1)  arc (80.0026:40:1) ;

 
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: A minimal working example as stated before is a complete compilable example. So basically one should be able to obtain a pdf document doing `pdflatex yourmwe.tex`, which is not the case at the moment. Please also take advantage of the formatting commands when editing your question so that the code is readable

Comment: Ok. How is that? I'm telling you this is the best I can do. Is there anything you can do to help me?

Comment: Maybe take a tour on the site and or type keywords with Google images linked to the site? You'll probably see an image related to a previous post that could be a starting point for your MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! This is a start. It is really just some basic nodes and path constructions and edges.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[semithick] (0,0) node[circle,draw,minimum size=5mm] (C){} circle[radius=2cm]
 (0,-4) node[draw,minimum size=5mm,label=below right:{$m\,g$},
    label=30:$P_1$](P1){}
 (0,-6) node[draw,minimum size=5mm,label=left:{$y=0$},
    label=30:$P_2$](P2){}
 (0,-2) coordinate (P) (C) -- (P1);
 \path[semithick,-Triangle,pos=0.9] (C.south) edge["$T$"] ++ (0,-1) 
 (P1.north)  edge["$T$"'] ++ (0,1) (P1.north) edge ++ (0,-1)
  (4,-2) edge["$a$"] ++ (0,-0.5) (4,-4) edge["$a$"] ++ (0,-0.5);
 \draw[-{Stealth[bend]}] (120:2.2) arc[start angle=120,end
 angle=150,radius=2.2] node[midway,above left]{$\alpha$};
 \draw[semithick] (C.120) to[out=30,in=180,looseness=0.6] (2.5,0) 
    to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.6] (3,0.2)  node[right]{$I$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What effect do the quotation marks in `edge["$T$"]` have?

Comment: @corvus_192 This is a short-hand, enabled by the `quotes` library, for `edge label={$T$}`.